# Getting started Asterisk and Twilio

Tags: twilio, asterisk

Twilio offers a great guide for the Asterisk users, and I followed it step by step (https://www.twilio.com/docs/documents/35/AsteriskTwilioSIPTrunkingv2_1.pdf)

The problem is that at the moment of the call the twilio servers are said UNREACHABLE by Asterisk, even if the machine can ping them perfectly

```
[Nov  9 07:46:08] NOTICE[19561] chan_sip.c: Peer 'twilio5' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Nov  9 07:46:08] NOTICE[19561] chan_sip.c: Peer 'twilio4' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Nov  9 07:46:08] NOTICE[19561] chan_sip.c: Peer 'twilio6' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Nov  9 07:46:08] NOTICE[19561] chan_sip.c: Peer 'twilio1' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Nov  9 07:46:08] NOTICE[19561] chan_sip.c: Peer 'twilio0' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Nov  9 07:46:08] NOTICE[19561] chan_sip.c: Peer 'twilio3' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
[Nov  9 07:46:08] NOTICE[19561] chan_sip.c: Peer 'twilio2' is now UNREACHABLE!  Last qualify: 0
```

There is also an additional perplexity on why I see chan_sip.c, even if I fully configured the pjsip.conf, is it normal?

In addition, I have no fail2ban, no iptable on, it's just failing

UPDATE:

I tried to make a tcpdumpo when I make a call, and two things come up:

1) Instead of showing the external ip (34.233.200.60), it shows the internal amazon one: 172.31.27.253

2) "Authentication failure - bad user credentials" seems pretty clear per-se, but I triple checked the account and password but it is still coming up

3) On Twilio I added the both internal and external ip to the list of authorized IPs, termination and origination, but still no luck

```
IP 54.172.60.0.sip > 172.31.27.253.sip: UDP, length 545
E..=..@...[66.<..........)..SIP/2.0 403 Forbidden
CSeq: 32523 INVITE
Call-ID: 511289ce-601a-4714-95a2-b062cdc1a22d
From: "asd" <sip:1001@172.31.27.253>;tag=50172bc0-130d-431b-a91b-d8e9e641cb69
To: <sip:+16504756086@rasterisk2.pstn.twilio.com>;tag=43545804_6772d868_5ca9a156-c7de-4ef5-93e1-f5846a68b2fb
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 34.233.200.60:5060;received=34.233.200.60;rport=5060;branch=z9hG4bKPj55b4041f-dfb6-4a06-974f-bc8b7f12672a
Server: Twilio
Contact: <sip:172.18.20.116:5060>
X-Twilio-Error: 32202 Authentication failure - bad user credentials.
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon is NATed environment.

So when you use SIP server!!! after nat you have inform it about NAT.

For more info see

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

Comment: It seemed the Asterisk-Twilio guide was accounting about the NAT (trasport-tcp-nat)

Comment: You should forward ports on amazon and inform asterisk about amazon external ip.

Comment: From my Voip Client I can connect to the machine at the 5060 port (no extra configuration) and I followed the twilio guide on the sip.conf section which informs asterisk of the external ip. Any other suggestion? How should I inform Amazon?

Comment: So your voip client more intelegent :) Anyway you shoudl setup like described on link above+open ports.